# Quantum dot integral so hard to crack! Please help if you can

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, numerical-methods, special-functions

The following equation arises while solving the Hamiltonian expectation energy for my quantum dot calculations and I plan to use variational approach to minimize the energy ($\beta$ is the variational parameter). 
$$\int_0^{100} \frac{e^{-2\beta[\rho^2 + (z-z_i)^2]^{1/2}}}{[\rho^2 +(z-z_i)^2]^{1/2}}dz$$
where $\rho = 50$ and $z_i$ will be varied from 0 to 20.

question: is there a way this integral could be solved either analytically/numerically (say even for a simple case when $z_i$ = 0)?

Thanks for the help

Comment: How large is $\beta$?

Comment: It looks like a u-substitution should work

Comment: Based on the previous work, I expect $\beta$ to be in the range $0<\beta<1$

Comment: This is however a part of a very large problem indicating the integral I have trouble solving. I would greatly appreciate your help. Thanks.